# Notary init not working with Microsoft azure container registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I am facing a problem with notary init while using at Microsoft Azure container registry, following are the logs

```
administrator@xyz:~/mayank-azure-test$ notary init testhelloworld.azurecr.io/hello-world -d /home/administrator/mayank-azure-test/docker-trust -s https://notary.docker.io -D -v
DEBU[0000] Using the following trust directory: /home/administrator/mayank-azure-test/docker-trust
DEBU[0000] No yubikey found, using alternative key storage: no library found
DEBU[0000] Making dir path: /home/administrator/mayank-azure-test/docker-trust/tuf/testhelloworld.azurecr.io/hello-world/changelist
DEBU[0000] No yubikey found, using alternative key storage: no library found
Root key found, using: e439e12df11382c860bf6aaa0d24c263546d55b6cb724b1d9f896a1ce7d0195a
DEBU[0000] No yubikey found, using alternative key storage: no library found
Enter passphrase for root key with ID e439e12:
DEBU[0006] generated ECDSA key with keyID: 638a47f7dfdcf0f08f66bbf108780eb8a4acffc3db7ec71f64b87f2d221954cb
DEBU[0006] generated new ecdsa key for role: targets and keyID: 638a47f7dfdcf0f08f66bbf108780eb8a4acffc3db7ec71f64b87f2d221954cb
Enter passphrase for new targets key with ID 638a47f:
Repeat passphrase for new targets key with ID 638a47f:
DEBU[0011] generated ECDSA key with keyID: c6a8021ac620c9f5a3185b55fa24b7b5948b8dcde3a4c7529e5dbab6c52139a2
DEBU[0011] generated new ecdsa key for role: snapshot and keyID: c6a8021ac620c9f5a3185b55fa24b7b5948b8dcde3a4c7529e5dbab6c52139a2
Enter passphrase for new snapshot key with ID c6a8021:
Repeat passphrase for new snapshot key with ID c6a8021:
Enter username: TestHelloWorld
Enter password:

* fatal: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
administrator@xyz:~/mayank-azure-test$
```

I also tried docker login to verify which worked –

```
administrator@xyz:~/mayank-azure-test$ docker login testhelloworld.azurecr.io
Username (TestHelloWorld): TestHelloWorld
Password:
Login Succeeded
administrator@ip-10-0-0-159:~/mayank-azure-test$
```

Comment: Can you do it with another docker image, not from ACR?

Comment: Yes, I was able to sign the file using docker hub with the same process

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The command is incorrect. You are specifying the dockerhub notary server:
 -s https://notary.docker.io -D -v

For ACR registry, the notary server is the same as your registry server (testhelloworld.azurecr.io).

If you just want to push signed image, the easiest is to use docker cli instead of notary cli:

set DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
docker push testhelloworld.azurecr.io/hello-world:latest

Comment: Thanks for help Yu Wang