# Unable to run az acr check-health command on MacOS

Tags: docker, azure-cli, azure-container-registry, health-check, azure-cli2

I am unable to run a health check using the Azure CLI. I am on MacOS Monterey. Below is the error:

```
➜ az acr check-health -n <ACR_NAME>
Docker daemon status: available
Docker version: 'Docker version 20.10.12, build 459d0df, platform linux/amd64'
This will pull the image mcr.microsoft.com/mcr/hello-world:latest. Proceed? (y/n): y
Docker pull of 'mcr.microsoft.com/mcr/hello-world:latest' : OK
Azure CLI version: 2.33.1
DNS lookup to <ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io at IP 20.42.66.2 : OK
Challenge endpoint https://<ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io/v2/ : OK
Fetch refresh token for registry '<ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io' : OK
Fetch access token for registry '<ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io' : OK
Helm version: 3.8.0
An error occurred: NOTARY_COMMAND_ERROR
Please verify if notary is installed.

Please refer to https://aka.ms/acr/errors#notary_command_error for more information.
```

The support URL provided does not lead to anywhere useful.

Not sure if it helps, but I'm able to login to my ACR just fine:

```
➜ az acr login --name <ACR_NAME>
Login Succeeded
```

Has anyone else faced this error/issue? What am I missing here?

Comment: Try downgrading your notary.exe version to a version earlier than 0.6.0 by replacing your Docker installation's Notary client manually to resolve this issue.

You can also try downloading and installing a pre-compiled binary of Notary earlier than 0.6.0 for macOS X from the Notary repository's releases page on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

According too [azure/container-registry| Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-content-trust#behind-the-scenes).

> Azure Container Registry does not officially support the Notary CLI
> but is compatible with the Notary Server API, which is included with
> Docker Desktop. Currently Notary version 0.6.0 is recommended

So please try the suggestion provided in comment by @madhuraj.

It looks like a known issue .See if below can be workaround.

Try to enable content trust at the registry level.

[image]

Or
In Bash

```
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
```

Enable content trust for single command

```
docker build --disable-content-trust=false -t myacr.azurecr.io/myimage:v1 .
```

In azure CLI

```
$ docker push myregistry.azurecr.io/myimage:v1
```

Please check [enable registry content trust | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-content-trust#enable-registry-content-trust) for further details.

```
$ docker pull myregistry.azurecr.io/myimage:signed
```

Or see  [azure container registry - Stack Overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806103/notary-init-not-working-with-microsoft-azure-container-registry)

```
set DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1

docker push myregistry.azurecr.io/image:tag
```

If the issue remains please raise a support request from overview blade > Support + troubleshooting >New Support Request.

**References:**

1. [https://docker-docs-notary](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/notary/getting_started/#:%7E:text=of%20your%20content.-,Install%20Notary,-You%20can%20download)
2. [Registry authentication options - Azure Container Registry |
   Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli)
3. [behind-the-scenes  - Azure Container Registry | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-content-trust#behind-the-scenes)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and fixed it by the following command (installing notary v0.6.1)

```
$ go install github.com/notaryproject/notary/cmd/notary@v0.6.1
```

See https://github.com/notaryproject/notary for what the notary is.

...

And well, the command was useless though (sigh

Answer (score 0):

set `AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=1` and voila, you won't get NOTARY_COMMAND_ERROR with `az acr login` command.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the original post, I am able to `az acr login` just fine. The issue I am seeing is with the `az check-health` command.